# Wordpress: how to do a custom query with ACF subfield

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a group field called "anagrafica" inside there is a field called "codiceFiscale"

no metter I try: this query is giving always 1...

```
$cf = $_POST['cf'];
        // args
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'anagrafica_codiceFiscale',
                    'value'   => $cf,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            while( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                //$nome -> the_title();
            }
            wp_send_json(array('response' => 0));
        }
        else {
            wp_send_json(array('response' => 1, $cf));
        }
```

any hint?? :(

Comment: What kind of value `anagrafica_codiceFiscale` contain?

Comment: it contains text